# Can't access user photo using client id and secret

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use the Unified API (Microsoft.Graph 1.0.1) to access my users profil photos, but I only get the following error back when accessing the photo:

> Code: ErrorAccessDenied
>   Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.

Accessing/Listing the other user profile data works fine and my application was added as a "Company Administrator" via [PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/issues/5) and has all rights set in the management portal. When I use the [GraphExlorer](https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/) logged in with my admin user it also works fine. Also via the "old" Azure Active Directory Graph API I can read/write to the users thumbnail photo, but thats not the one showing up in Office 365.

**How can I get the appropriate access rights to perform actions on users profile photo?**

This is the code I use (shortened to the parts in question):

```
class Program
{
    private const string authStringMicrosoft = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_APP_ID/";

    private const string clientID = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
    private const string clientSecret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET";

    private const string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncContext.Run(RunAsync);

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var token = await GetAppTokenAsync(authStringMicrosoft, graphResourceId);
        var authHelper = new AuthenticationHelper() { AccessToken = token }
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authHelper);
        await ListUser(graphClient);
    }

    private static async Task ListUser(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User-List:");
        var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{user.UserPrincipalName}:\t\t{user.GivenName} {user.Surname}");
            if (user.UserPrincipalName == "USER_WITH_PICTURE")
            {
                var graphUser = graphClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName];
                var graphPhoto = graphUser.Photo;

                var photoInfo = await graphPhoto.Request().GetAsync(); // <= here the exceptions is thrown
                Console.WriteLine($"{photoInfo.Id}:\t{photoInfo.Width}x{photoInfo.Height}");

                var photoStream = await graphPhoto.Content.Request().GetAsync();

                byte[] photoByte = new byte[photoStream.Length];
                photoStream.Read(photoByte, 0, (int)photoStream.Length);
                File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\User.jpg", photoByte);
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync(string authority, string azureGraphAPI)
    {
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(azureGraphAPI, clientCred);
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
}

public class AuthenticationHelper : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

I use the following NuGet-packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.24.304111323" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Nito.AsyncEx" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

This is an example request delivering the error (using postman with the token read out from the app above):

> GET /v1.0/users/MY_USER_WITH_PHOTO/photo/ HTTP/1.1
>   Host: graph.microsoft.com
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1...
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
>   Postman-Token: e756a8a3-22e2-d40c-8e52-15c4d1aa7468
>   Accept: */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>   Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

And the response:

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>   Cache-Control: private
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   request-id: 96e8dda8-2353-4891-8c42-99cfe7e22887
>   client-request-id: 96e8dda8-2353-4891-8c42-99cfe7e22887
>   x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_4","ADSiteName":"DUB"}}
>   Duration: 1367.7691
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Sun, 01 May 2016 17:57:02 GMT

Body:

> {
>    "error": {
>      "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
>      "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
>      "innerError": {
>        "request-id": "96e8dda8-2353-4891-8c42-99cfe7e22887",
>        "date": "2016-05-01T17:57:02"
>      }
>    }
>   }

Again, if I remove the `/photo` from the request I get all common user details without a problem.

Here the permissions of my app (web-app):
[image: permissions]

Here a decrypted access token:

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "MnC_VZcATfM5pOYiJHMba9goEKY",
 kid: "MnC_VZcATfM5pOYiJHMba9goEKY"
}.
{
 aud: "https://graph.microsoft.com",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/11205e59-fa81-480f-b497-571579c5389a/",
 iat: 1462795409,
 nbf: 1462795409,
 exp: 1462799309,
 appid: "c34a87ef-352a-4af4-a166-eb7e521a0ec9",
 appidacr: "1",
 idp: "https://sts.windows.net/11205e59-fa81-480f-b497-571579c5389a/",
 oid: "1db8c6b5-10ba-40ac-bbff-86ab440c4fd3",
 roles: [
  "Mail.ReadWrite",
  "Device.ReadWrite.All",
  "User.ReadWrite.All",
  "Calendars.Read",
  "Group.Read.All",
  "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
  "Contacts.ReadWrite",
  "Group.ReadWrite.All",
  "Directory.Read.All",
  "User.Read.All",
  "Mail.Read",
  "Calendars.ReadWrite",
  "Mail.Send",
  "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite",
  "Contacts.Read"
 ],
 sub: "1db8c6b5-10ba-40ac-bbff-86ab440c4fd3",
 tid: "11205e59-fa81-480f-b497-571579c5389a",
 ver: "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTTP request and response including headers for a failure case?  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp and see if that helps

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT Thanks, but I already managed to get the request/response using postman - please see my updated question: at the end I included an example

Comment: Thanks for the info!   Will ask my team to take a look and get back to you.

Comment: @ChrFin can you tell us what permissions you've configured/requested as part of your app configuration please? Or better still can you decrypt your token (using something like jwt.calebb.net) and tell us which "roles" have been granted to your application please?

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT I have added the permissions and a decrypted token to the end of my question. Aside from that permissions I added the app the role "Company Administrator" via PowerShell like shown in the link above. Thanks for looking into my problem!

Comment: @ChrFin - Thanks for the info.  We are following up.

Comment: @ChrFin - please update your application to request permissions for Microsoft Graph (not Azure AD).  Please make this change and you *should* see a "roles" claim show up in the token. To read the user's token you'll need to select the user.read.all permission (Read users' profile data or some such). Our permissions are described here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes. Also is this a single tenant app (are you running this app in the same tenant as you've registered the app when using the Azure Management Portal)?

Comment: @ChrFin - correction in my last comment - to read the user's PHOTO (not token).  BTW I believe this *should* solve your problem.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT Thanks for the help, this already got me forward "half-way" - using an access token like the one I added now to the question I am able to read the users pictures, but when trying to write a new one using `graphPhoto.Content.Request().PutAsync(fileStream)` I'm getting the same error again (I gave my app all permissions in MS Graph and Exchange Online for testing). Is there anything else I need to set up to also be able to write?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else reads this when getting that error. I had this same error when creating my own graphClient and the reason I got it was due to using a non-admin account with...

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Select().GetAsync();
```

With a non-admin account, you only have access to some basic properties like lastname, firstname etc - this worked for me...

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Select("mail,givenName,surname").GetAsync();
```

Comment: i also needed the following in my web.config...<add key="ida:GraphScopes" value="User.ReadBasic.All"/>